# Is it valid to use `command` inside of $(())

Tags: bash, shell, sh

Is it valid to use a backticked command:

```
`command`
```

inside of `$(())`?

For example, like this:

```
d=$((`date +%s`+240))
```

I tried this in a shell script and from the prompt, and it works:

```
#!/bin/sh -u

# get the date in seconds with offset
d=$((`date +%s`+240))
echo "d=\"${d}\""
echo "date:%s=\"`date +%s`\""
```

But, if I check it at http://www.shellcheck.net/, I get this error:

```
1  #!/bin/sh -u
2
3  # get the date in seconds with offset
4  d=$((`date +%s`+240))
     ^––SC1073 Couldn't parse this $((..)) expression.
     ^––SC1009 The mentioned parser error was in this $((..)) expression.
        ^––SC1072 Unexpected "`". Fix any mentioned problems and try again.
5  echo "d=\"${d}\""
```

My ***bash*** version is:

```
[~] # bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.1.2(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)
Copyright (C) 2009 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
```

And, to be clear, on my system, `sh` actually runs `bash`:

```
[~] # ls -l /bin/sh; which bash
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4 Jul 18  2013 /bin/sh -> bash
/bin/bash
```

I submitted feedback about this at http://www.shellcheck.net/, but I haven't heard back from them yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While `$(( 1 + 1 ))` is allowed in POSIX (e.g. http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html and section 2.6.4), some shells might not support it.

The classic way to do `$(( $(date +%s)+240 ))` is like this:

```
d=$( expr $( date +%s) + 240 )
```

Here, we use `expr`, which has been around longer than `$((`.

Note that, as per other answers, I have replaced the backtick with `$(` since, unlike the backtick, it can nest, like it does above.

Comment: Is there a diffrence between `$(())` and `$()`? You seem to use them interchangeably.

Comment: Yes.  `$(( ))` is for arithmetic expansion; `$(( 1 + 1 ))` returns a 2.  `$( )` is for command expansion and is equivalent to the backtick (except for being cleaner looking and netstable operation; $( ls ) returns a list of files.  `$( expr 1 + 1 )` is equivalent to `$(( 1 + 1 ))` since `expr` acts like a basic calculator.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is perfectly valid. But [it is not recommended](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/obsolete) to use backticks at all. You can use `$()` instead.

Answer (score 1):

According to `man bash`, inside an arithmetic substitution (`$((expression))`): (emphasis added)

> The  expression  is  treated as if it were within double quotes, but a double quote inside the parentheses is not treated specially.  All tokens in the expression undergo parameter expansion, string expansion, **command substitution**, and quote removal.

So as far as bash is concerned, it is legal, since backticks are a form of command substitution. But the `$(...)` form of command substitution is preferred.